# is there a way to store arm64 assembly code in module using LLVM API?

Tags: assembly, llvm, arm64

I'm currently working on a compiler project using llvm.
I have IR Module , But I want function which takes IR module as argument and return  Assembly module of TARGET(ARM64 or aarch64).

.My goal is to create an  such function, and I am confused as what to do next. I can print machine code or assembly code on terminal but unable it store in module.  for transforming IR module into specific target machine code I am using addPassesToEmitFile() function but unable to store in module.

Comment: Do you want your compiler to produce assembly or to place inline assembly inside your llvm module?

Comment: Assembly . I written a function which generate assembly code using addPassesToEmiltFile() but it is only printing on terminal I want that assembly code to store in LLVM module . So that I can do verification or analysis of each instruction one by one.
I already have IR module and I am giving that module as an argument for my generateAssembly function .